# 写真アップロード時に自動的にリサイズできる方法をご教授お願いします

Tags: javascript

某顧客様向け申込受付システムの提案を検討しております。
顧客からは
1.本人証明書をサイトからアップロードさせたい。
2.アップロード時には自動的にリサイズしてファイル容量を圧縮したい。

上記考えてくれないかと要望を頂いております。
1だけであれば容易いのですが、2を実現するにはどの様にすればいいのか現在調べております。

知見のある皆様　ご教授の程お願いします。

Comment: Javascriptタグがついていますが、サーバサイドもJavascriptになりますか？そのほか言語やサーバの制約があれば追記ください。

Comment: 実はサーバサイドについてはまだ何も決めておりません。

Comment: ということは、クライアントサイドでJavaScriptを使用して画像ファイルの解析、リサイズ、容量削減を行いたいということでしょうか？

Comment: そうですね。可能であれば　クライアントサイドで画像ファイルの解析、リサイズ、容量削減を行い、その後POSTメソッドをを使い、サーバー側（のフォルダー）にファイルを送りたいと考えております。